# call form 1 function from another form

Tags: c#, .net

```
public partial class UserLoginForm : Form
{
   private void LoginForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     Common.UserLoginFormObject = this;  //Store UserLoginForm Object in Static class Common.
   }
   private void DoSomething()
   { 
     //some code
   }
}

public partial class MainForm : Form
{
        private void cmdLogOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Common.UserLoginFormObject.DoSomething();//Now here i have to call Dosomething function.
        }
}
```

How to 
call form 1 function from another form.

Comment: @HenkHolterman he already has object of `UserLoginForm`!no need to make it static..

Answer (score 3):

Make DoSomething function Public

```
public void DoSomething()
{ 
  //some code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to call `DoSomething` method there should be a object `Common.UserLoginFormObject` make sure you create `new UserLoginForm()` where you assign object to `Common.UserLoginFormObject`. and also you need to make DoSomething method public.

as  Henk Holterman  mentioned by comment you can make `DoSomething` method static then you don't need to have object to call that method.